# Spring security : cannot access permitAll endpoints

Tags: spring-security

I have this `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration :

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/auth/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .oauth2Login()
            .authorizationEndpoint().baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
            .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
            .and()
            .redirectionEndpoint()
            .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
            .and()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
            .and()
            .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler)
}
```

And I don't understand why I got a 401 when I try to access the `/favicon.ico` or `/oauth2/**` endpoints.

What am I missing ?

Comment: If you turn the `org.springframework.security` logs up to `DEBUG`, what does it say? Also, `permitAll` doesn't prevent authentication, it just removes that requirement; if creds are being presented in the request, Spring Security will still try and authenticate (and succeed or 401 accordingly).

Comment: I found with debug mode enabled, that `@EnableResourceServer` was overriding my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I need to find a way to keep my oauth2 external provider configuration works with the resource server configuration.